# How to create scrollable tabs?

Tags: android

I am working to create scroll able  tabs, please help me out, I am using below code, but not work for me

```
   <TabHost
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<HorizontalScrollView
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
</HorizontalScrollView>
<FrameLayout
               android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Please let me know specific answers

Comment: Surround the Tab contents with `<ScrollView> ... </ScrollView>` maybe ?

Comment: thanks for suggestion, since i have used horizontal scroll view, but it doesn't work for me ? any clue

Comment: You might have used `HorizontalListView`, but since your contents are vertical, did you set it explicitly to vertical (the default is horizontal)? The `ScrollView` on the other side doesn't require any additional modifs, just enclose the `LinearLayout` with the tags from above, or you can also try to enclose the contents of the `LinearLayout` with the <ScrollView> ... </ScrollView> tags (whatever suits you best).

Comment: yes gOOdy,na i was using horizontal scroll view, yes its work for me , i had taken linear layout vertical, thanks for you help :)

Comment: Is there anything acceptable in my suggestions or you found the solution your self? If the last is true, then paste the results here or tell me which part worked for you, so I can post the answer. Thanks

Comment: Try this: `<LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TabWidget
     android:id="@android:id/tabs"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ScrollView>
<FrameLayout
               android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:padding="5dp" />
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>`

Comment: gOOdy, its yet not works , by this code

Comment: What are you receiving? I mean what is not working :-) Does it just not scroll ... let's move it to a char maybe ?

Comment: Parent should be Tab host,then it will work, and then scrolling is not done.

Comment: If the content of the Tab is in the `TabWidget` and not in the `FragmenLayout`, then the `ScrollView` should enclose this.

Comment: g00dy: could you send me code, what are you trying to say,I have tried, not working yet

Comment: Something like the code in the answer below, but instead of `<HorizontalScrollView>` to put `<ScrollView>`.

Comment: Is this solution working for you, or you found another? Welcome anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is works for version 2.2+

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TabHost
        android1:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <HorizontalScrollView android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fillViewport="true">
                    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_weight="0.0" 
                        android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected"/>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help shubniggurath :)

Answer (score 3):

**This Code work for 3.0 and higher versions :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:fillViewport="true"
                     android:scrollbars="horizontal"

                   >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

          <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
      </LinearLayout>
      </HorizontalScrollView>
      </LinearLayout>
      </TabHost>
```

But not for lower versions,I need to make work for scrollable tabs for all devices